# Bootstrap 4 modal that contains markdown header link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following code to open a bootstrap 4 modal that contains a Markdown header link. The modal opens correctly but does not scroll to the correct header. I think this is because the page loads before the modal opens. Is there an event for triggering the scroll to header? Would that event be within showdownjs (what I'm using) or is it a standard implemented within the browser?

```
let split_url = location.href.split('#');
$(".modal:has(#" + split_url[split_url.length - 1] + ")").modal('show');
```

Comment: Are you sure $(".modal:has(#" + split_url[split_url.length - 1] + ")") finds your modal? Add this code before that: if ($(".modal:has(#" + split_url[split_url.length - 1] + ")").length == 0)alert('not found');

Comment: Yes it finds it because the modal opens correctly it just doesn't scroll to the header.

Comment: Scroll to header?! It just shows the modal, why should it scroll to header?

Comment: When the markdown is outside of a modal it scrolls automatically. Here is an example url https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#images that scrolls to the `images` header

Comment: So your modal content has a named tag and you want to scroll the content of the modal down, right? If yes, you cannot use the #url to scrool to your named tag. Use JQuery scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Here a workaround I eventually came up with.

```
let split_url = location.href.split('#');
let active_modal = $(".modal:has(#" + split_url[split_url.length - 1] + ")");
let offset_top;
active_modal.modal('show').on("shown.bs.modal", function (event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (typeof offset_top === 'undefined') {
            offset_top = $("#" + split_url[split_url.length - 1]).offset().top;
        }
        active_modal.animate({ scrollTop: offset_top  }, 'slow');
    },300)
});
```

It isn't perfect because the scroll is delayed. I couldn't get it to be instantaneous like it normally is.